# .net chart clear and re-add

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a chart and I need to clear it in order to populate it with different values.
The chart has 3 series, all defined in the .aspx page.

The problem is when I call

```
chart.Series.Clear();
```

and then re-add the series like:

```
chart.Series.Add("SeriesName");
```

It doesn't keep any of the attributes of the 3 initial series.
How to just clear the values and keep the series attributes?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach(var series in chart.Series) {
    series.Points.Clear();
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I use this then re add the same values only 2 of the 3 series are re populated. One is missing any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
 chartnameHERE.Series["SeriesNameHERE"].Points.Clear();
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as ACCEPTED.

Answer (score 2):

This will actually completely remove the series from the chart (not just remove the points from the series).

```
while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I Faced kind of problem(but for windows form Application). So can you please tell me when are you passing the datasource to the charts.

I Used incorrect order while passing the data to the chart control

**At first time I did this :**

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Auto;

chart1.DataSource = sqlChartTabel; //sqlChartTable is my DataTable
// Assigning new Data to the charts
chart1.Series.Clear();   // clearing chart series (after the DataTable is assigned with data)
chart1.Series.Add("Violations");
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Month_name";
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Salary";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Months";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Salary";
chart1.DataBind();
chart1.Visible = true;
```

So, then I realized, I am Assigning the data before clearing the chart so I just changed my statement order, And It Worked :

**My Working code :**

```
chart1.Series.Clear();   // changed position of clear(before Assigning the datatable)
chart1.Series.Add("Violations");
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Auto;
chart1.DataSource = sqlChartTabel;   //sqlChartTable is my DataTable

// Assigning new Data to the charts
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Month_name";
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Salary";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Months";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Salary";
chart1.DataBind();
chart1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
foreach(var series in chart.Series)
{
    series.Points.Clear();
}
reloadData();
this.chart.DataBind();
```