# How to clear plotted values in points chart?

Tags: c#

In my C# application ,using a points chart that is working fine. But if I try to clear all plotted points it is not clearing. How to do this?

Refer below the code,

```
series1.Points.AddXY(1, 10);//Plotting the points in chart
series2.Points.AddXY(2, 20);
chart1.Series.Clear(); //I tried to clear using this code
```

If i tried the above code for clear , it is removing entire chart but I want to clear only the plotted points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net chart clear and re-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019086/net-chart-clear-and-re-add)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clear all the points in the series:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
```

To remove the first point in the series:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
```

To clear all the points in all  series:

```
foreach(var series in chart1.Series) 
{
    series.Points.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Tron: i tested your suggestion and it is clearing successfully but if i try to add the values in the series (this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);) , it is throwing exception like "Series already added exception". how to add existing series in the graph again?