# Chart series clearing not working

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, series

I need to call CreateChart() in several times in my C# application. But an error says

> Additional information: A chart element with the name 'Income' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'.

I cleared the Chart series using the below piece of code.

```
foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
    {
        series.Points.Clear();
    }
```

Took the above code from [stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019086/net-chart-clear-and-re-add)

But still same issue comes. Here is the CreateChart(). It loads the chart for the first time without having an issue. If I load it multiple times, error occures.

```
foreach (var series in chart1.Series)
                {
                    series.Points.Clear();
                }
                chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
                var IncSeries = new Series("Income");
                var ExpSeries = new Series("Expense");
                IncSeries.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { "Today's Income" }, new[] { Income });
                ExpSeries.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { "Today's Expense" }, new[] { Expense });
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
                chart1.Series.Add(IncSeries);
                chart1.Series.Add(ExpSeries);
```

Comment: "I cleared the Chart series using the below piece of code" - No, that code clears the point collection of each series in the chart's Series collection.  Instead of just looking for code to copy, make an attempt to understand it.  Once you learn the basics of how stuff works, you can build from there without needing to find code to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't cleared series. You've only cleared points in series.

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
var IncSeries = new Series("Income");
var ExpSeries = new Series("Expense");
IncSeries.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { "Today's Income" }, new[] { Income });
            ExpSeries.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { "Today's Expense" }, new[] { Expense });
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
chart1.Series.Add(IncSeries);
chart1.Series.Add(ExpSeries);
chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
```